# Tips on deploying Ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, amazon-ec2

How can I go about deploying a Rails app on a cluster of Amazon EC2 servers?  Any recommended guides?

I maintain a RoR app (currently hosted on Heroku) that uses a DB and DelayedJobs).  The app has a large footprint, and needs to be distributed on a cluster most likely.  Any tips would be appreciated.  Are there Amazon AMIs that replicate some of Heroku's features (especially DJ)?

P.S. I'm quite a Ruby newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason it can't stay on Heroku?  You can scale Heroku dynos and workers as you see fit, and can upgrade to a dedicated database instance if it really needs it.

Comment: The app is very IO intensive, and requires a lot of workers to scale well.  Heroku charges a fortune for workers, rather than charges for CPU usage.

Comment: Have you looked into the Engine Yard cloud?  They handle the configuration of the servers, you just turn on however many you need.

Comment: yes, I did, and it does seem good; however, I want to compare it to managing it myself.  Also, there is a public value to an answer.

Comment: Given that you're new to Ruby/Rails, I wouldn't recommend diving in and trying to manage your own servers.  EY/Heroku have done all the hard work of handling the optimizing, backups, caching, monitoring and scaling.  You could probably find an EC2 AMI that's ready with Rails, Passenger/Nginx, etc -- but it's not going to be a beautiful cluster that's ready for production.  Also, know that with EY cloud you'll need to familiarize yourself with Chef.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a clean (ebs-based) AMI from Alestic or Amazon and configure it myself. It's very difficult to find an appropriate AMI (or several for web-server, app-server, DB-server and make them work together) and a high risk to trust it.